# completely uninstalling software and accompanying components

Tags: windows-7, installation, visual-studio-2010

As a student in computer science, I find myself installing many useful software applications for computer programming on Windows.  One software application in particular that I enjoy using on Windows is Visual Studio.  I recently installed Visual Studio on my computer, but uninstalled it for personal reasons.  One mistake I made prior to installing VS was not paying attention to exactly ALL of the additional components that are additionally installed along with the IDE.  The components I am talking include: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - command line utilities, data-tier app framework, express localdb, management objects, native client, transact-sql scriptdom, ...and the list goes on.  Eventually, I can't tell which components are part of which installation.

Another example of this is when I install many software programs and end up with many a hundred different copies of the microsoft visual c++ redistributable.

My main question is if there is some program I can use or some way I can organize the additional components that get installed along with a software application.

Comment: try the uninstall utility for VS2010: http://aka.ms/vs2010uninstall

Comment: Organize? In what way?